# Highcharts - draw line chart with summed values but show breakup on hover

Tags: ajax, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts - Line - Ajax. 
Let's say I have two series of data - 'Headcount 1' and 'Headcount 2'. I want to draw a line graph of 'Headcount', which is the sum of the 2 series. However, when someone hovers on one data point, I want to show the individual values in the callout. Is this possible? How can I do this?

e.g.

```
H1 = (1, 2, 3)
H2 = (5, 6, 7)
Ht = (6, 8, 10)
```

I will draw a line graph with Ht. If I hover on '6' on the chart, the callout should show the values of H1 = 1 and H2 = 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the visibility for series H1 and H2 to false,

```
series: [{
        name: 'H1',
        data: [1, 2, 3],
        visible: false,
        showInLegend: false
    }, {
        name: 'H2',
        data: [5, 6, 7],
        visible: false,
        showInLegend: false
    }, {
        name: 'H',
        data: [6, 8, 10]
    }]
```

and edit tooltip formatter to display what you want

```
tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
          var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
          var chart = this.points[0].series.chart; //get the chart object
          var categories = chart.xAxis[0].categories; //get the categories array
          var index = 0;
          while(this.x !== categories[index]){index++;} //compute the index of corr y value in each data arrays           
          $.each(chart.series, function(i, series) { //loop through series array
              if (series.name !== 'H') {
                s += '<br/>'+ series.name +': ' +
                    series.data[index].y +'m';  //use index to get the y value
              }
          });  
          return s;
      },
      shared: true
    }
```

Have a look at [jsfiddle.net/s190ebby/27/](http://jsfiddle.net/s190ebby/27/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes
Points can have custom property, taking care that the names do not shadow highcharts variable names.

```
var data = [{
    y: 6,
    h1Value: 1,
    h2Value: 5
},{
    y: 8,
    h1Value: 2,
    h2Value: 6
}];
```

Set your series to this data in your config object, by `series: data`

Customise the tooltip as:

```
tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '<b>H Value</b>: {point.y}<br/>
                        <b>H1 Value</b>: {point.h1Value}<br/>
                        <b>H2 Value</b>: {point.h2Value}'
}
```